# Exporting React Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have started to learn ReactJS, I have a question about this case. `const` is used before declaration and it doesn't throw error. Why?

```
import React from "react";

export class item extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <div style={customStyle}>test</div>;
  }
}
const customStyle = { color: red };
export default item;
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with react and is javascript thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Using* means *accessing*. If you would construct a new item instance and call it's render method before the `const customStyle` line, then it would throw.

JS does not semantically enforce that a variable declared with `let` or `const` cannot be used before it's initialization, it is just a runtime error to do so.

The same behaviour can be seen if you access variables that don't exist at all:

```
 function see() {
   console.log(a); // not a semantical error, this is totally fine ...
 }

 // ...unless you try to execute it
 see();
```

Answer (score 3):

The reference to `customStyle` is inside a function, so it is resolved only when the function is called, which is after all the definitions have been processed.